# Questions about what the [x=,y=] option in \draw means?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

In Section 2.12 Parabola and Sine Path Construction of [A Picture for Karl’s Students](https://tikz.dev/tutorial#sec-2.12),
one can draw the parabola and sine paths using the following commands.

**Parabola**

`\tikz \draw[x=1pt,y=1pt] (0,0) parabola bend (4,16) (6,12);`

**Sine paths**

`\tikz \draw[x=1.57ex,y=1ex] (0,0) sin (1,1) cos (2,0) sin (3,-1) cos (4,0) (0,1) cos (1,0) sin (2,-1) cos (3,0) sin (4,1);`

What do the `[x=1pt,y=1pt]` and `[x=1.57ex,y=1ex]` exactly achieve in the draw options? I play around a little bit and observe that if `x` is larger, then the parabola and sine paths become longer. But if I increase `x` further the line also becomes thinner. I wonder if it is the two dimension scaling options for drawing on a 2D plane, or it has its own purpose in the drawing of parabola and sine paths respectively.

Comment: These two options are well described in [the manual](https://tikz.dev/tikz-transformations#sec-25.2). With `x` and `y` you essentially set the basic unit for the horizontal or vertical axis in the Ti*k*Z picture. The default for both is 1cm.

Comment: In your example, you use these two options in the context of a single path by applying them directly to the `\draw` command. In this case, they have only an effect on this path. You could also set them globally using `\tikz[x=1pt,y=1pt]` or the like, and then you would essentially scale the whole Ti*k*Z picture.